# Is my reasoning correct for the following linear congruence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I am given 2x = (1+3i) mod (3+8i). Here are my steps:

1. I found that 1 = (-1)(3+8i) + 2(2+4i).
2. I took mod (3+8i) and got 2(2+4i) = 1 mod (3+8i).
3. Then I took the product (2+4i)(1+3i) and got -10 + 10i.
4. Lastly, I took -10 + 10i mod (3+8i) and obtained 3-4i

Is this correct?

Comment: What ring are your working in?? Are you trying to do some arithmetic in the Gaussian integers? What ideal do you have... **or what** ?

Comment: Yes to arithmetic in Gaussian integers. We have not talked about rings yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything is correct. It can be done a bit  more simply as follows.

${\rm mod}\,\ 3\!+\!8i\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{3\equiv -8i}\ \Rightarrow\  \color{#c00}3i + \color{#c00}3\!-\!2\, \equiv\, (\color{#c00}{-8i})i\! \color{#c00}{-8i}-\!2\, \equiv\, 6\!-\!8i$

Therefore we conclude $\ 2x\, \equiv\, 3i\!+\!1\,\equiv\, 6\!-\!8i \iff x \,\equiv\, 3\!-\!4i$

Comment: Cancelling $\,2\,$ is valid by $\,2\,$ is coprime to $\,\alpha =3+8i,\,$ since it has odd norm $\,\alpha\bar\alpha = 73.\ $ Indeed, since $\,\alpha\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, \alpha\bar\alpha=73\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\,2(37)\equiv 1\ \ $